# HBase addColumn and setFilter

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I am scanning HBase by setting Scanner with only specific column names I want and a range of columns using column filter.

Adding individual rows:

```
known_fields.forEach(known_field ->scanner.addColumn("x".getBytes(), known_field.getBytes()));
```

Also I am adding a Column filter:

```
scanner.setFilter(new ColumnRangeFilter(start, true, stop, true));
```

All the variables have correct values. And I am scanning as below

```
    scanner.setCacheBlocks(false);
    scanner.setBatch(1000);

    ResultScanner results = null;
    Table table = null;
    try {
        table = connection.getTable("table_test");
        results = table.getScanner(scanner);
        boolean hasPerformed;
        for (final Result result : results) {
        ...
```

The `results` is always null. But, If I comment out either `scanner.setFilter(new ColumnRangeFilter(start, true, stop, true));` or `scanner.addColumn(`, the result is perfectly fine. It isn't working with combination.

How to achieve the combination of known columns and a range of columns?

Comment: you can find answers in this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/IZHkQl169Hw

Comment: @maxteneff: Thanks. But the solution there is remove the addColumn completely because in that use case the addColumn attribute is part of the ColumnRange. My use case is different. And i need to use `Scan`, not `Get`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have small number of columns for `scanner.addColumn`, you can use [FilterList](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/FilterList.html) with `MUST_PASS_ONE` operator and passing to it multiply `ColumnRangeFilter`. Add column to scan is this case equivalent to add ColumnRangeFilter with coincide start and end columns. E.g.

```
Filter filter = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ONE);
known_fields.forEach(known_field -> 
      filter.addFilter(new ColumnRangeFilter(known_field.getBytes(), true, 
                                             known_field.getBytes(), true));
filter.add(new ColumnRangeFilter(start, true, stop, true));
scan.setFilter(filter);
```